# How to check every pandas series value is unique

Tags: python, pandas

I know how to count the number of unique values in pandas series (one column in pandas dataframe).

```
pandas.Series.value_counts
```

But how do I check if they are all unique? Should I just compare value_counts with its length?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

IIUC, `pd.Series.is_unique`

```
pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).is_unique
True
```

And

```
pd.Series([1, 2, 2]).is_unique
False
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `nunique`

```
pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).nunique()==len(pd.Series([1, 2, 3]))
Out[62]: True
```

Answer (score 3):

`pd.Series([1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan]).is_unique`

`> False`

It will give `False` for this which it should not.

Comment: In my understanding, there are duplicates (np.nan) in your list so it should return False. You may have to dropna() before calling is_unique

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan]).dropna().is_unique
True
```

Will solve the problem posed by [swapnil athawale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59043839)